# Customer stated three options of international payment?

Tags: banking, international-transfer, online-payment

My customer asked one of three options of payment types (for remittance) **from USA to UK**.

These are:

(1) Intl-Wire - Domestic to foreign

(2) ACH - Domestic to Domestics

(3) IAT - Domestic to Domestics

--------- I want to know their difference.

Comment: Welcome new user, someone has finally clearly answered your question for you!  :)

Answer (score 1):

## wire is your only option of those three:

1. for USA->UK wire transfer costs $20-$50 and takes a few days. it's a huge PITA getting all the data correct for a wire transfer, take extreme care.<sup>†</sup>
2. ACH is ONLY for within the USA so irrelevant to you.  (it is free and takes a day or so, but has no connection to USA->UK)
3. "IAT" or "Global ACH" is not available these days so forget it.  it's bizarre they mention it

Of the three mentioned **wire transfer is your only option**

Here's a perfect **article** explaining:

https://transferwise.com/us/blog/international-ach-transfer

## nobody uses wire transfers these days, just use a transfer service:

Other options:

1. if it's a small amount of money (under $500 say) inevitably it's easier to just use PayPal or similar in some way (fees will be very high)
2. **What everyone does these days for international payments:** just use one of the two major international payment companies, **OFX** or **Transferwise**.

- you do have to set up an account which is a bit annoying (however, setting up an account is much easier than making just one old-style wire transfer). once you set up an account you're set for life
- once the account is set up, it's extremely easy to send money USA->UK. it takes seconds
- it is far faster and cheaper than wire transfer.
- more importantly, it's the best possible exchange rate (dollars to pounds) you can get

---

<sup>†</sup> *this site is flooded with questions "my wire transfer went missing, what to do..."*

Comment: What will document be initiated by sender's bank for wire transfer?

Comment: Hi Hussain, if you want to send a TT, it depends on the bank.  (A) in many cases you have to go in to the branch.  (B) sometimes you have to send a fax to the bank  (C) often there is an online interface.  The person GETTING the wire transfer must ask THEIR bank for the "wire transfer address".  Then of course give that information to the person SENDING the TT.  OK ?

Comment: Bank to Bank Info:- DPF DB CASE 201217603993-001 UTA BENE DO NOT HOLD USD ACC SSN 0248388 DATED 12/17/20 ----------- What does it mean

Comment: Hi, your question has been (fully) answered, please tick it, it would be best to start a new question to seek information on your new question!  Good luck!